# Examples of systems programming projects (OS, DB, filesystem, game, server) written with functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, system

I'm interested in the ideas of functional programming but every substantial project example I've come across has been a simple input->output transform (like a compiler for example).

Does anybody know of any system projects? I would be really interested to see how it's done. The examples don't have to be production level or actually performance competitive - I'm just looking for something substantial. 100k+ lines for example.

Comment: I believe compilers generally *are* considered systems software. Also Ericson's systems that Erlang was created for should certainly qualify (I don't think those are open source though, so I guess that doesn't help you in terms of examples you can look at). Then FP languages are relatively popular in the financial sector and I assume that kind of software would also qualify as systems. Again, not open source though.

Comment: RabbitMQ requires Erlang as a dependency as well. I'm not really sure what for, though  - whether the whole of RabbitMQ is in Erlang or just a subcomponent. Not sure what RabbitMQ is written in, either. But might be worth looking into.